# *** These critical programs are missing or too old: make compiler when installing GLIBC_2.29 on centos7

Tags: linux, centos7, nvidia, glibc

Hi I want to install GLIBC_2.29 on centos7 and I using this commands

```
wget -4c https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.29.tar.gz
tar -zxvf glibc-2.29.tar.gz
cd glibc-2.29
mkdir build_dir
cd build_dir
sudo ../configure --prefix=/opt/glibc
sudo make
sudo make install
```

at sudo ../configure --prefix=/opt/glibc I get this error

```
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for readelf... readelf
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking whether g++ can link programs... no
checking for sysdeps preconfigure fragments... aarch64 alpha arm csky hppa i386 m68k microblaze mips nios2 powerpc riscv s390 sh sparc x86_64 checking whether gcc compiles in -mx32 mode by default... no

checking for use of fpu sysdeps directories... yes
checking for -fstack-protector... yes
checking for -fstack-protector-strong... yes
checking for -fstack-protector-all... yes
checking for assembler and linker STT_GNU_IFUNC support... yes
checking for gcc attribute ifunc support... yes
checking whether the linker supports textrels along with ifunc... yes
checking if compiler warns about alias for function with incompatible types... no
checking sysdep dirs... sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/64 sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64 sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86 sysdeps/x86/nptl sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/wordsize-64 sysdeps/x86_64/nptl sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux sysdeps/nptl sysdeps/pthread sysdeps/gnu sysdeps/unix/inet sysdeps/unix/sysv sysdeps/unix/x86_64 sysdeps/unix sysdeps/posix sysdeps/x86_64/64 sysdeps/x86_64/fpu/multiarch sysdeps/x86_64/fpu sysdeps/x86/fpu sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch sysdeps/x86_64 sysdeps/x86 sysdeps/ieee754/float128 sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-96 sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/wordsize-64 sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64 sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32 sysdeps/wordsize-64 sysdeps/ieee754 sysdeps/generic
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /bin/install -c
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking whether as is GNU as... yes
checking whether ld is GNU ld... yes
checking for as... as
checking version of as... 2.27, ok
checking for ld... ld
checking version of ld... 2.27, ok
checking for gnumake... no
checking for gmake... gmake
checking version of gmake... 3.82, bad
checking for gnumsgfmt... no
checking for gmsgfmt... no
checking for msgfmt... msgfmt
checking version of msgfmt... 0.19.8.1, ok
checking for makeinfo... makeinfo
checking version of makeinfo... 5.1, ok
checking for sed... sed
checking version of sed... 4.2.2, ok
checking for gawk... gawk
checking version of gawk... 4.0.2, ok
checking for bison... bison
checking version of bison... 3.0.4, ok
checking if gcc is sufficient to build libc... no
checking for nm... nm
checking for python3... python3
checking version of python3... 3.9.6, ok
configure: error: 
*** These critical programs are missing or too old: make compiler
*** Check the INSTALL file for required versions.
```

Comment: Your gcc compiler is too old to build glibc-2.29. Either upgrade it or build another glibc version.

Comment: "checking version of gmake... 3.82, bad" I did not see a problem with the compiler but the gmake... from your logs.

Answer (score 0):

> Hi I want to install GLIBC_2.29 on centos7 and I using this commands

Obviously you need to use newer `make` and `gcc`.

But after you've successfully built and installed the new GLIBC into `/opt/glibc`, you will *probably* try to use it by setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/glibc/lib` or similar ... which would *not* work.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617) for what you'll need to do next.

**Under no circumstances** try to copy libraries from `/opt/glibc` into your system library directory, create equivalent symlinks, or add the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` above systemwide -- that will render your system un-bootable!